# FTP "No transfer timeout" while transferring files with Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftp-client, ftplib

Not very knowledgeable with FTP servers... Transferring a large amount of data (in textual format) from the NOAA (National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration) FTP server and inserting it to a SQL Server. It went well for several tens of millions of rows until I got to the largest file I had yet ran into at ~2.5MB [of text only].

```
for file in ftpList:
    if file.endswith(".gz") and not failedRun:
        flo = io.BytesIO()
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, flo.write)
        flo.seek(0)
        with gzip.open(flo, 'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                ## REPLACE FUNCTION FOR QUERY FILE ##
                cursor.execute(qry_wx)
                cursor.commit()
```

When trying to run this larger than normal file, this is the error that I receive:

```
2021-01-02 12:07:19,558-ERROR-Error: 421 No transfer timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PythonProjects\ISH\WX_TO_DB.py", line 72, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, flo.write)
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 441, in retrbinary
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 278, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 251, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "E:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in getresp
    raise error_temp(resp)
ftplib.error_temp: 421 No transfer timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection
```

I tried to change the timeout parameter in the initial call to the FTP class to >300 seconds, but have since learned that this no transfer timeout is a default from the FTP server and I cannot change it.

I wish I could better explain the issue but like I said I'm fairly new to this and don't fully understand the retrbinary method. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

The server has limit, for how long you can not transfer any file, before the server terminates the connection.

As a workaround, first download all files. And only then process them.